# Does the table in the FROM clause have to be in the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I've done a similar JOIN in a UPDATE script, but I used the same table in the SET and WHERE clause. In this DELETE script I need to delete from one table where a condition is true in another table. For example:

```
DELETE FROM `db_A`.`table_A`
JOIN `db_B`.`table_B`
ON `table_A`.`id` = `table_B`.`id`
WHERE `table_B`.`name`  = 'Remove Me'
```

Can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The [MYSQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) makes it very clear that yes you can do this

> You can specify multiple tables in a
>   DELETE statement to delete rows from
>   one or more tables depending on the
>   particular condition in the WHERE
>   clause. However, you cannot use ORDER
>   BY or LIMIT in a multiple-table
>   DELETE. The table_references clause
>   lists the tables involved in the join.
>   Its syntax is described in Section
>   12.2.8.1, “JOIN Syntax”.
>
> For the first multiple-table syntax,
>   only matching rows from the tables
>   listed before the FROM clause are
>   deleted. For the second multiple-table
>   syntax, only matching rows from the
>   tables listed in the FROM clause
>   (before the USING clause) are deleted.
>   The effect is that you can delete rows
>   from many tables at the same time and
>   have additional tables that are used
>   only for searching:

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

> Or:

```
DELETE FROM t1, t2 USING t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

> These statements use all three tables
>   when searching for rows to delete, but
>   delete matching rows only from tables
>   t1 and t2.
>
> The preceding examples use INNER JOIN,
>   but multiple-table DELETE statements
>   can use other types of join permitted
>   in SELECT statements, such as LEFT
>   JOIN. For example, to delete rows that
>   exist in t1 that have no match in t2,
>   use a LEFT JOIN:

```
DELETE t1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
The syntax permits .* after each tbl_name for compatibility with Access.
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Delete Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html), the table you want to delete goes between `DELETE` and `FROM`. Unless you want to delete from all tables involved in the join

```
DELETE `db_A`.`table_A` FROM `db_A`.`table_A`
JOIN `db_B`.`table_B`
ON `table_A`.`id` = `table_B`.`id`
WHERE `table_B`.`name`  = 'Remove Me'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer, yes. You can join to the second table with the condition, as you have stated, or pull the ids in a subcommand, like:

DELETE FROM T1
WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON X = Y WHERE T2.Val = "X")

This is a bit heavy weight, but if T2 is the child, you can reduce this to:

(SELECT Y from T2 WHERE Val = "X")

Make sense?